Avoid reloading Pytorch datasets
I train CNNs on a relatively stable combination of datasets, but every time I start a training job, there's a 5-10 min wait for the trainer to load my dataframes from disk.  Is it possible to avoid this step and load the data only once and have to available for multiple processes to access?
The assumptions is that I may start and tear down multiple training jobs, tinker with training parameters, topologies, but the data will be the same.
I feel a client-server solution may be relevant, where one process loads the datasets once and then services requests from multiple training clients.  Has this been done before?  Is there a readymade framework that already implements this?

The short answer is while you could do something like this, it's probably more work than it's worth. You're better off speeding up the dataset loading. For example, instead of loading the full dataset into memory, use a library like datasets and use more worker processes for your dataloader

Hello @Karl, thank you for this pointer.  The biggest hog is a .csv file that takes forever to load (annotations).  I currently cache it into a .parquet file.  This saves time, but is still time-consuming.  I've tried ramfs, but it makes little difference.  I use Pandas to read these files (either csv or parquet).  Maybe this is the bottleneck?

Well, I never tried before this, I was just patiently waiting for cached instance to load lol
But I did find something from googling, try using redis. It is a python library that allows you to store things in RAM and retrieve them. I never tried it myself but here is some simple code to run it, like:
import redis # pip install redis
df = pandas.read_csv('dataset.csv')
r = redis.Redis(host="localhost", port=8888, db=0) # start a localhost server on this port 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    r.hmset(f"row:{index}", row_to_dict()) #load data in RAM

Then in another program:
data = r.hgetall("row:0") #OR you can try iterating through the data

There are also another implementation using multiprocessing shared_memory thing. I copied this one from gpt, but legit to me.
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

# Create some data (example: an array)
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=np.int32)

# Create shared memory block
shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=data.nbytes)

# Create a NumPy array using the shared memory buffer
shared_array = np.ndarray(data.shape, dtype=data.dtype, buffer=shm.buf)

# Copy data to shared memory
np.copyto(shared_array, data)

print("Shared memory block created with name:", shm.name)
print("Data written to shared memory:", shared_array)

# Remember to close the shared memory if it's no longer needed in this process


And in another program:
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import shared_memory

# Replace 'your_shared_memory_name' with the name printed by the first script
shm_name = "your_shared_memory_name"  # Use the name from the first script

# Access the existing shared memory block
existing_shm = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shm_name)

# Create a NumPy array using the shared memory buffer
shared_array = np.ndarray((5,), dtype=np.int32, buffer=existing_shm.buf)

# Read the data from shared memory
print("Data read from shared memory:", shared_array)

# Clean up
existing_shm.close()

Again, this COULD solve your problem. Try and let me know :D

Also, it is not guranteed in real life and never done in enterprise. It takes enormous amount of resources (especially for big datasets). They most likely use cached instances.
